# ESP8266 + Arduino Uno + ESP8266WIFI lib

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm having a problem with ESP8266 in programming part.
I'm using Arduino Uno and have thousand times run programs.
It's has been my second day in completing my esp8266 simple fully function circuit

My current problem is :

1. ESPwifi library has many error even I download it from official github source code

So, I decided to use WIFIESP library and it stuck at TIMEOUT/NO WIFI/NO MAC ADDRESS

2. I cannot use pin 0 & 1 because a wire stuck in it.

I have search everywhere to solve my problem even tough needs alternative ways I will at least doesn't required NEW HARDWARE.

Reupdate : 08:18 PM 4.3.19

I just want steps without need AT firmware & able to post data to websites
I don't want extra boards EXCEPT:
Arduino UNO
ESP8266-01 (small one with 8 pin)

Windows 10 with arduino IDE latest version

Comment: "ESPwifi library has many error" What you mean by that? Have you tried the hello world first?
What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Actually I mean when I select my arduino uno board and runs the ESP8266WiFi.h library it appears many error that talking about missing files but if I change to ESP8266 board it say about comm_mem failed and I search about it that to resolve that problem choose correct board so and again it a waste . Right now, I`m walking through ESP without AT. Is there I did mistakes or left something behind ?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Arduino IDE but I would suggest you check [Platformio](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif8266.html) which handles the library installation. Also, there are [good articles](https://www.losant.com/blog/getting-started-with-platformio-esp8266-nodemcu) to getting started with.

Comment: Alright thank you so much  I check it now and will send updates later

Comment: Well, I have checked your link. Actually it's not same with my esp8266 mine is 01 model. I really misunderstanding with that esp8266 wifi module. Some article says that esp8266 01 already builtin AT but when I run AT commands there no output

Comment: It supports almost all esp8266 modules and the 01 models also support it and by the way actually, it doesn't make any difference. Also, you should check that the current firmware of your ESP module is fine, you can use [this link](https://www.electronicshub.org/update-flash-esp8266-firmware/) to update it.
Also, every ESP module should support AT commands if they have the right firmware.

Comment: Wow, I never tough this one . Alright I will go through one by one very nice link thank you so much ☺️.

Comment: There are many bad reports about that tutorial in comments section. I really don't want to broke this esp thing

Comment: if you want to post data to website, just use `ESP8266HTTPClient` library. If you understand the structure of HTTP, you can use `WiFiClient` library. There are some type of data you can't post with `ESP8266HTTPClient` library, for example: uploading file (multipart/form-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your real problem is, but here is my solutions:

In case you haven't install the esp8266 boards for the arduino IDE yet, then you should install it first. The installation instructions is documented on [GitHub](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager). Here is the snippet to install ESP8266 boards on Arduino IDE:

1. Start Arduino and open **Preferences** window.
2. Enter `http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json` into ***Additional Board Manager URLs*** field. You can add multiple URLs, separating them with commas.
3. Open **Boards Manager** from **Tools** > **Board menu** and install esp8266 platform (and don't forget to select your ESP8266 board from **Tools** > **Board menu** after installation).

ESP Libraries needs Arduino Core Library to work. If you haven't install the board yet, then you will get many errors.

hope this help.